# Rolling sum previous 12 months grouped by 2 dimensions (SQL- Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table structure available in the C:

I am struggling in Snowflake with a query that should show me the the sum of previous 12 months for every distinct month in the table split into three dimensions .

The way reporting date 01.08.2022 for region='US' and type=1 is calculated: it is the sum of the past 12 months' row of "revenue_12_months" = 4000+ 45433+45777+ 8866+ 4000+ 6678+ 2456+ 6677+ 6677+ 7744+ 6775 + 7755

```
    WITH
    indata(dt,region,type,revenue) AS (

          SELECT DATE '2021-04-01','US','Type 1',4000 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-05-01','Europe','Type 2',5777
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-05-01','US','Type 1',45433 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-07-01','Europe','Type 2',8955
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-06-01','US','Type 1',45777 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-09-01','Asia','Type 1',7533
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-07-01','US','Type 1',8866 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-01','Asia','Type 2',5534
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-08-01','US','Type 1',4000 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01','Asia','Type 1',7244
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-09-01','US','Type 1',6678 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-03-01','Asia','Type 1',5654
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-10-01','US','Type 1',2456 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-05-01','Asia','Type 1',4525
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-01','US','Type 1',6677 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-01','Asia','Type 1',6654
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-12-01','US','Type 1',6677 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-09-01','Asia','Type 2',5754
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01','US','Type 1',7744 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-11-01','Asia','Type 2',5644
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-01','US','Type 1',6775 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-01-01','Asia','Type 2',6777
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-03-01','US','Type 1',7755

    )
    
    select dt,region,type, SUM(revenue) OVER (ORDER BY dt,region,type ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) revenue_12_months
    from indata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it per region and type, so that needs to part of the `partition by` clause

```
sum(revenue) over (partition by region, type order by dt rows between 11 preceding and current row)
```

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you simply forgot the GROUP BY part in your window function?

```
     WITH
    indata(dt,region,type,revenue) AS (

          SELECT DATE '2021-04-01','US','Type 1',4000 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-05-01','Europe','Type 2',5777
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-05-01','US','Type 1',45433 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-07-01','Europe','Type 2',8955
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-06-01','US','Type 1',45777 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-09-01','Asia','Type 1',7533
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-07-01','US','Type 1',8866 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-01','Asia','Type 2',5534
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-08-01','US','Type 1',4000 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01','Asia','Type 1',7244
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-09-01','US','Type 1',6678 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-03-01','Asia','Type 1',5654
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-10-01','US','Type 1',2456 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-05-01','Asia','Type 1',4525
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-11-01','US','Type 1',6677 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-01','Asia','Type 1',6654
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2021-12-01','US','Type 1',6677 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-09-01','Asia','Type 2',5754
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01','US','Type 1',7744 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-11-01','Asia','Type 2',5644
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-01','US','Type 1',6775 UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-01-01','Asia','Type 2',6777
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-03-01','US','Type 1',7755

    )
    
    select dt,region,type, SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY region, type ORDER BY dt,region,type ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) revenue_12_months
    from indata
    ORDER BY REGION, TYPE, DT;
```

Best regards,

TK

Comment: sorry but somehow I can't add an "Hi timy" at the start of my answer.